# jquery.marquee.js can not run with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-1.5

i'm a newbie of AngularJS (using v1.5) anh now I have a problem: I use javascript jquery.marquee (https://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin) in html same that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.marquee').marquee({
            duration: 5000,
            gap: 50,
            delayBeforeStart: 0,
            direction: 'up',
            duplicated: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

but it shows error "marquee is not a function" (as image that I have attached)

[image]

---

i have putted it in html:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js" 
        type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Did you loaded the `jquery-marquee-plugin `.

Comment: i have putted it in html: 
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.marquee/1.4.0/jquery.marquee.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: Directly enter `marquee ` on console & check if the object exists or not.

Comment: i have a <div> tag with class = "marquee" and it always exitst

Comment: Please add code and errors as **text** ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors in text format are much, *much* better than code/errors as an image, which are somewhat better than nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error.

Answer (score 0):

Just try using $.noConfilct() function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.marquee').marquee({
            duration: 5000,
            gap: 50,
            delayBeforeStart: 0,
            direction: 'up',
            duplicated: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the `jquery` library before loading the `marquee` plugin:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.marquee').marquee({
        duration: 5000,
        gap: 50,
        delayBeforeStart: 0,
        //direction: 'up',
        duplicated: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/jquery.marquee"></script>

<div class='marquee'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit END.</div>
```